# What verb to use to denote researching something informally?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

The verb "research" generally fits into academic or otherwise professional settings. As Oxford English Dictionary defines it, research is

> 1. Investigate systematically
>
>    > 1.1 Discover or verify information for use in (a book, programme, etc.)

With this in mind, what verb can I use to describe the research that I did in a setting similar to the following:

> I just found out that we can go to St. Clements during our visit to London.

Would I say

> I was looking into where we could visit and just found out that we can go to St. Clements during our stay in London.

or is this acceptable

> I was researching about where we could visit and just found out that we can go to St. Clements during our stay in London.

Alternatively, you may also consider this

> I was investigating where we could visit and just found out...

Here is the definition of "investigate" in Oxford English Dictionary:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/investigate

Comment: I like "look into."   Also, you can lower the formality of "research" by saying "internet research" instead, e.g. "I did some internet research."

Answer (score 2):

*Looking into* sounds most natural in my opinion. *Researching* and *investigating* both sound too formal. I think this is a matter of idiom or usage ― simply the way people speak ― rather than a dictionary definition. Now that many people use the Internet to answer their questions, I suppose research is what they are doing. But to say "I was investigating where we could visit" is to risk sounding very pretentious. *Research* and *investigate* are too inflated for the mere act of looking at a few websites without needed any special skills to find out what the favorite tourist spots are.

Comment: I think it depends to the situation of getting the right information or idea.
Using internet pages: "I visited some tourist information sites on the web and discovered an amazing place called St. Clements." or " I spend 2 days in comparing all available flight prices. Finally, flights in September will be the cheapest."